# I touch an iAd and Xcode recognizes I also touched the background

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I have a game where I have an ad on the top. My game has an action that is triggered whenever the user touches the background. It just so happens that when I click my ad, the said action is triggered, as if I had just touched the background!
Any ideas on a fix to this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set your `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate and implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method  `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view == iAdView) { 
            return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This code excludes target view from UIGestureRecognizer.

Do not forget to set `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES` for your iAdView